# Email input types unexpectedly "unhighlighted" by jquery.validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have the following model (simplified), **note that both `Email` and `Text` are not `Required` fields**:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And the following view:

```
@model MyModel

@using (Html.BeginForm)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Email)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Text)

    <button id="my-button" type="button">Button</button>
}
```

I would like to trigger client-side validation when `#my-button` is clicked so I have the following event handler:

```
$(function() {
    $('#my-button').click(function() {
        $('form').valid();
    });
});
```

So far so good. The only issue I am having is, I don't want the `input[type="email"]` field to be [`unhighlight`ed](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#unhighlight) when users open the form and click the button without filling in anything as this is contradictory to the other `input[type="text"]` field's behaviour where it isn't `unhighlight`ed.

Is that possible?

Comment: You would need a `[Required]` attribute if you want the input to be invalid if its empty.

Comment: @StephenMuecke actually i want the opposite behaviour, I want both `input`s to remain neutral (i.e. not `unhighlighted`, can't think of a better term) when the `button` is clicked, unless a value is entered

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the following set up. With this you can call `valid()` on the document load and this will highlight the form straight away until you enter values into the fields.

The Class (note the `[Required]` attributes):

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

The View:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)    
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.email)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.email)

    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Text)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Text)

    <button>Submit</button>
}
```

This will use the jQuery Unobtrusive Validation package linked via your Model to validate the form. 
If you need them, you can get the packages via the following id's in NuGet:

`jQuery.Validation`

`Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation`

As a sidenote, if you require the ability to validate the Email address field entry to be a true email address try the following package `dataannotationsextensions` in NuGet. Also see: http://dataannotationsextensions.org

This will allow you to add further attribute info to your Model like:

```
    [Required]
    [Email]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

(There are probably loads more packages out there that do the above email validation)

If visually the field doesn't highlight as you expect, please check the CSS file to make sure `input[type=email]` is covered as well as `input[type=text]`

Comment: Both fields are not required in my form, I have updated my question

Answer (score -1):

focus your input if there isn't any val in your input after click the button

```
 $('#my-button').on('click', function() {
        var $input = $('input[type=email]');
        if ($input.val()) {
            $form.valid();
        } else {
            $input.focus();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question